# C# Generic Tree with multiple payload types

Tags: c#, generics, tree

Is there a way to accomplish a generic tree data structure where nodes on each hierarchy level could hold different (and typed) payload objects?

I'd like to be able to query the tree with a key and get back a typed result, not an object. I've tried with generic interfaces but it seems I'm still needing to write separate query routines for each payload type. A generic solution would be more elegant, albeit casting from just one generic method is problematic. Maybe there is no way?

Also all the implementations in CodePlex or GitHub seem to allow just one payload type that is then used in all nodes in the whole tree. I want separate payload objects at each hierarchy level.

Thanks, Pom

Comment: If you want to store *anything* on any node then store an `object`. You will incurr in boxing if the stored object is a value type, but there is nothing you can do about it unless there is some kind of *commonality* you can leverage on the objects you want to assign to any given node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an object tree (i know you don't want it, but see no other option) and your method to query you can set a type.

For example, `tree.Query<T>()` and returns a list of T elements.

Hope it helps.